# how to send email via smartermail?

Tags: c#, smtp

What is smartermail? How can i send mail via smartermail installed on server?
Any smtp settings in web.config?

Comment: could you provide more details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SmarterMail](http://www.smartertools.com/SmarterMail/Features/Windows-Mail-Server-Software-Webmail-Exchange-Alternative.aspx) is an SMTP mail server, so you could use the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class to send mail:

```
var client = new SmtpClient("hostnameOfYourSmtpServer");
var from = new MailAddress("from@example.com");
var to = new MailAddress("to@example.com");
var message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Subject = "test subject";
message.Body = "This is a test e-mail message sent by an application. ";
client.Send(message);
```

Comment: what do i replace hostnameOfYourSmtpServer with?